# Pdf content does not show with Intent

Tags: android

I have create simple Pdf page, saving it to internal app dir and trying to open it with Intent.
PDF viewer doesn't show any content, but when I copy the file to download dir and open it manually everything works.

```
private fun showPdfDocument() {
    val pdfDocument = PdfDocument()

    val paint = Paint()

    val pageInfo = PageInfo
        .Builder(500, 800, 1)
        .create()

    val page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo)

    val canvas: Canvas = page.canvas

    paint.setTextSize(15f)

    canvas.drawText("Title", 209f, 100f, paint)
    canvas.drawText("Description", 209f, 80f, paint)

    pdfDocument.finishPage(page)

    val file = File(requireContext().externalCacheDir, "report.pdf")

    try {
        pdfDocument.writeTo(FileOutputStream(file))
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        pdfDocument.close()
    }

    openPdfFile(file)
}

private fun openPdfFile(file: File) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    val uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        requireContext(),
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider",
        file
    )
    intent.setDataAndType(uriForFile, "application/pdf")
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "")
    startActivity(chooser)
}

<paths>
<files-path name="internalFiles" path="/" />
<external-cache-path name="cache" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Seems like you haven't shared the cache location in your file provider path. Can you share your file_provider path xml file?

Comment: You'll need to add the cache path to your file provider: `<external-cache-path name="name" path="path" />`. See here for more info https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal shared

Comment: Ohh the `external-cache-path` is present already. It should've worked. Can you try choosing some other application when the chooser pops up? 
Perhaps try giving `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` permission as well, though I'm pretty sure `READ` permission is all that it needs.

Comment: Modify `<external-cache-path name="cache" path="/"/>` to `<external-cache-path name="cache" path="." />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From FileProvider Docs:

> A FileProvider can only generate a content URI for files in directories that you specify beforehand.

You must specify a child element of `<paths>` for each directory that contains files for which you want content URIs. In your case you'll have to add this to the `<path>` element:

```
<external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="." />
```

Comment: I don't understand what happen, I just replaced `path="/"` to path="." and it's start to work, then I  reverted the changes back and it's still work, it just blow my mind